# async method calls within catch blocks

Tags: c#, async-await

Is there a way to call an `async` method within a catch block?

At the moment I have an application which logs exceptions with an `async` / `await`ed method but I can't put this in a catch block because I'm told:

```
The 'await' operator cannot occur inside a catch or finally block of a try-statement, inside the block of a lock-statment or in an unsafe context.
```

At the moment I'm having to assign the exception to a variable inside the catch block and then call my `await logException()` afterwards.

Whilst this isn't the end of the world, it seems like there should / could be another / better way.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Currently in C#5, no, there's no way to do it directly.

In [C# 6 / Roselyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation), it's already implemented.